# Difference between Geometries created by NetTopologySuite 6 and 8

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, nettopologysuite

I have an EF Core `DbContext`, that used to use EF Core 6 with NetTopologySuite.
I use it to edit a database that's used by a different C# .NET application, that I do not control.
When I inserted Geometries with that version, they were compatible with that application.

Now I have updated EF Core to version 8 (and with it, NetTopologySuite), but now the Geometries that my code creates are somehow different, but I could find no documentation of a change in NetTopologySuite.

This is what the difference looks like in SSMS:

"Old"-Geometry binary: `0x00000000010D00000000806DD4C000000000605D14410000000000308140`
"Old"-Geometry WKT: `POINT (-20918 333656)`

"New"-Geometry binary: `0x00000000010F00000000806DD4C000000000605D14410000000000308140000000000000F8FF`
"New"-Geometry WKT: `POINT (-20918 333656)`

The 2 geometries represent the same WKT, but somehow have completely different binary.

My goal is to create the "old style" binary with my code, but I have no idea what to change.

Comment: I have opened an issue in the [NetTopologySuite Github-project](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite/issues/740)

Comment: I doubt that this has to do with NetToplogySuite. NetTopologySuite.IO.SqlServerBytes is the better project wrt binary read/write, but I suspect EF / your SQL backend is responsible for this.

Comment: What I have tried so far after posting this question is: Running my program with EF Core 8 and with EF Core 6, and looking both at the NetTopologySuite "Geometry" object (which looks the same in every property to me) and the INSERT statements that are logged by EF Core, which in both cases just show the binary that is written to the database. But what I need is the step of generating the binary representation from the "Geometry" object, and I can't seem to find that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the difference now: The "new" binary has an M-Value at the end.

The solution is to give my `NetTopologySuite.NtsGeometryServices.Instance` a `DotSpatialAffineCoordinateSequenceFactory` with `Ordinates.XYZ` as a parameter.

Then no M-Values are written into the binary representations, and the other program is happy.